# Adding customization on a standard field to an Un-managed package

Tags: managed-package, standard-objects, package, customization, unmanaged-package

I have added a bunch of custom pick-list values on the ***Type*** field on the ***Account*** object and want to make them available to the users who installs this un-managed package (ideally when a user installs this un-managed package the newly added pick-list options on the Type field on Account should be part of the package in someway) so that when the user goes to create a new Account record he/she finds the newly added pick-list options on the Type pick-list on the Account object, I have done a bunch of reading and couldn't find a clear way out. So here is what I am looking for:

1. Is there a way to do this via Eclipse?
2. Ant?
3. Normally via an un-managed/managed package?
4. Metadata API?

I'd like your thoughts on all the above mentioned approaches.

Thanks so much fellow stackexchangers!

Comment: What do you specifically mean by 'available to the users who installs this un-managed package'?

Comment: Hey @Maggie I have updated the question, let me know if its clear now. Thanks!

Comment: For managed packages, the pick lists options do not get updated during an upgrade. `During a package upgrade, no new picklist values are installed into the subscriber’s organization for existing fields` - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_behavior.htm

Comment: @Eric what is the best practice around publishing these changes to subscribers org? Thoughts?

Comment: @ShaikhMohdNadeem - Not sure. Since you cannot make callouts during a post install script and can't get a session ID from firing off a batch....I would be interested to know this as well. I have done it manually when the customer requests. Typically it is not a big issue as the customer can add it themselves if needed and your code is not restricted to the values in the pick list. The whole reason is so that what the customer has customized does not get removed on update

Comment: I see your point @Eric, makes sense, Thanks! Just wondering if there is a less cumbersome way to do this.

Comment: Looks like you got your answer.

Comment: @Maggie, yes this was indeed helpful.